# Hartalika vrata and it's rules

Tags: vrata

Hartalika vrata means hariyali Teej.

- Does that mean one has to eat a green fruit (hara fal) the day before the vrata day before going to sleep?
- On that day does one have to eat a bilvapatra with some water?
- Can we eat some sweets and have water after the pooja is complete?
- If someone doesn't eat anything and doesn't drink even a sip of water will it be considered *roza* (Muslims fast)?
- It is said in the hartalika vrat story that you should not sleep on that day of hartalika vrata.. does that imply it's about day and night also?

Comment: If someone does not drink water throughout the fast then that fast is called "Nirjala Upavasa". No need to borrow terminology from another religion because many people here may not know what that means.

Comment: You have many sentences ending with a "?" I guess all of those are your questions?

Comment: All questions are about rules of hartalika Teej vrata , so this question is exactly I want to know the rules. Which of these are right and which ones are wrong.

Comment: Yes understood, I have marked out all the questions you have.

Comment: In many fasts, they have to keep a night vigil (ratri jagaran). For e.g. the Shivaratri fast.

Comment: Is it necessary?